# Fix Message ER Rejected No Route Defined

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I'm trying to send a new order single message but I'm getting an ER Rejected message that says that the order reject reason is `UNKNOWN ORDER`, and `No Route Defined` but I couldn't find any explanation for this error.

If anyone knows what "No Route Defined" means I would be grateful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically this means the FIX engine and transaction infrastructure at the other end (it's usually a broker you are connecting to with FIX) does not know what to with the order you are sending to them. Specifically it does not know which exchange or other handling venue to route it to. Hence 'no route'.

This may be because it does not recognize the instrument in your order or some combination of parameters on your order are invalid. Although typically you would get a more informative error message if this were the cause.

Other causes include the broker's connection to a down stream handling system (e.g. exchange, trading desk) has been interrupted. Sometimes this is a transient situation - service interuption or time-of-day issue outside regular trading hours (RTH).

In any case the message indicates that a valid servicing destination for your the order can not be found at this moment.

Comment: The UNKNOWN ORDER error might also be a result of you trying to reuse an Order ID , either one of your own or one of the broker's.

Comment: I have verified if I'm reusing an Order ID and it seems unlikely to be this the problem. I have already verified if I'm sending the right message, the FIX configurations to connect with the broker, the dictionary I'm using, my code to see if there is something wrong. But everything looks OK, so if I have understood right, the problem is at the other end. I will talk with them to fix this problem and if I find a solution I will let you know. Thanks for your help and your time.

Comment: Post your entire FIX message and the entire response if you can. It'll be easier to see what's going on. There are no standards for FIX error messages, it is best just to contact your broker and ask them. Often the issue is at their end.

Comment: It ended to be a custom tag that was missing in my message, they forgot to tell me that I should pass a TraderID (custom tag that my broker asks in the message). Thanks a lot for your help Jimmy, your answer helped me to understand better this kind of problem.

Comment: Have you checked your cpty rules of engagement? Yeah, this is an error message that they've created on their side.